# C language - Read .csv file, problem with searching for a specific value

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, csv

I have a problem with my code. First i parse .csv file to array, after this i want to find a specific value. I use a binary search algorithm for this. The problem is to find specific value, because the program cannot find a value even though it sees it and returns incorrect values.

.csv file structure (ip number and flag):

```
192.168.0.1, D
...
192.168.2.255, M
```

.csv parser

```
static void read_csv(char* filename, dangerous_ip_addr** ip_ranking, int* array_length)
{
   FILE* fd = fopen(filename, "r");
   char line[20];
   int j = 0;
   int i = 0;
   char* token;

   for(char c = getc(fd); EOF != c; c = getc(fd))
   {
      if('\n' == c)
      {
         j++;
      }
   }

   *array_length = j;

   (*ip_ranking) = (dangerous_ip_addr*)malloc(j * sizeof(dangerous_ip_addr));

   rewind(fd);

   while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd))
   {
      token = strtok(line, ",");
      (*ip_ranking)[i].ip_addr = strdup(token);

      token = strtok(NULL, "\0");
      (*ip_ranking)[i].flag = strdup(token);

      i++;
   }

   fclose(fd); 
}
```

structure

```
typedef struct _dangerous_ip_addr
{
   uint32_t* ip_addr;
   char* flag; 
}dangerous_ip_addr;
```

binary research code

```
int binarySearch(dangerous_ip_addr* arr, uint8_t first_index_element, int last_index_element, const char* value_to_find) 
{ 
   while (first_index_element <= last_index_element) 
   { 
      int mid = first_index_element + (last_index_element - first_index_element) / 2;

      //Check if x is present at mid 
      if (0 == memcmp((const char*)arr[mid].ip_addr, value_to_find, strlen(((const char*)arr[mid].ip_addr))))
      {
         return mid;
      }
      else if (0 > memcmp((const char*)arr[mid].ip_addr, value_to_find, strlen(arr[mid].ip_addr)))
      {
         first_index_element = mid + 1; 
      }
      else
      {
         last_index_element = mid - 1; 
      } 
   }  
}
```

main function

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
   int array_length = 0; /* It's better to initilizie variable */
   dangerous_ip_addr* ip_ranking = NULL;
   read_csv(argv[1], &ip_ranking, &array_length);
   
   #ifdef _DEBUG
   const char* test = "192.168.2.203";
   printf("[IP]{%d}%s\n", (uint32_t)test, test);
   printf("[IP]{%d}%s\n", ip_ranking[place].ip_addr, ip_ranking[place].ip_addr);
   //printf("[MEMCMP]%d\n", memcmp((uint32_t)ip_ranking[place].ip_addr, (uint32_t)test, 12));
   printf("[%d == %d [%d]\n", (uint32_t)ip_ranking[place].ip_addr, (uint32_t)test, (uint32_t)ip_ranking[place].ip_addr == (uint32_t)test ?  1 : 0);
   #endif

   char* test =  "192.168.2.244"
   int result = binarySearch(ip_ranking, 0, array_length - 1, test); 

   printf("[PLACE]%d\n", result);
   printf("[IP NUM]%s\n",ip_ranking[result].ip_addr);
   printf("[FLAG]%s\n", ip_ranking[result].flag);
}
```

Output

```
[IP]{-673816572}192.168.2.203
[IP]{-648206912}192.168.2.203
[-648206912 == -673816572 [0]
```

I have no idea what to do with it. I will be grateful for any help! Have a nice day for everyone!

Comment: Looks like a fencepost-error.

Comment: Since [there's a `bsearch()` function in the standard library](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html), I can't see any good reason for reinventing this wheel. Also, `strdup()` returns a `char*` value, but `(*ip_ranking)[i].ip_addr = strdup(token);` assigns this result to a `uint32_t*` pointer. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Is the data sorted? Binary search won't be any use if it isn't.

Comment: @r3mainer because i use this implementation in another program, where ip addres i stored in uint32_t variable. So i'd like parse ip addr from csv file to uint32_t variable. If you have an idea for a better solution, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: @Stef, yes, data in csv file are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i resolved this problem on my own.

First, i change my structure, so that, i don't keep there an uint32_t value of ipv4 but i keep address in in_addr structure:

```
typedef struct _dangerous_ip_addr
{
   struct in_addr ip_addr;
   char flag; 
}dangerous_ip_addr;
```

Second, i change the way to save parsed IP address to structure. I use inet_aton method to calculate the value of IP addr from string to number.

```
   while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd))
   {
      struct in_addr IP_struct;
      token = strtok(line, ",");
      printf("[IPv6]%s", token);
      inet_aton(token, &IP_struct);
      tmp_ip_ranking[i].ip_addr = IP_struct;


      token = strtok(NULL, "\0");
      tmp_ip_ranking[i].flag = token[0];

      i++;
   }
```

This 2 solution give me a posibility to easier compare a 2 value, without cast it, because, now in the binary search, i can compare 2 value directly:

```
while (first_index_element <= last_index_element) 
{  
   int mid = first_index_element + (last_index_element - first_index_element) / 2;
      
   if (arr[mid].ip_addr.s_addr == value_to_find.s_addr)
   {
      return mid;
   }
   else if (arr[mid].ip_addr.s_addr < value_to_find.s_addr)
   {
      first_index_element = mid + 1;
   }
   else
   {
      last_index_element = mid - 1;
   }
}
```